# How to set styles to unrelated element if the parent has the particular class with CSS

Tags: css

I have a HTML structure like below.

```
<div class='A'>
    <div class='B' />
    <div class='C' />
</div class='A'>

<div class='D' />
```

**What I want to achieve:**

```
if A has C: add margin to D. (There is a chance that <C /> will not appear.)
```

Comment: That HTML example is thoroughly invalid. Do you really use that?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do something like that with just the markup you have.

In your template you probably have some kind of condition for the `class C`.

Maybe you can also add a condition to add an extra class to the `class A` element whenever the `class C` condition is true.

If class C is **not** rendered you will have

```html
<div class='A'>
    ...
</div class='A'>
```

If it **is rendered** then you would have something like

```html
<div class='A contains-c'>
    <div class='B' />
    <div class='C' />
</div class='A'>

<div class='D' />
```

and you could then use the following css

```css
.contains-c + .D {
  ...
}
```

There is a `has()`css pseudo-class coming, but it still has almost no support. You can read about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) if it interests you